# Oracle - Add all values in single column

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to add all the values in a column to get the total of that column, anyone know the trick to this?

Here's my query:

```
select T.*,
sum(nvl(BIN1,0))+sum(nvl(BIN2,0))+sum(nvl((BIN3,0)) as TOTAL
from
(
  SELECT CSM_FLASKS.FLASK_CODE,
    MN_ASSAYS_STAGES.ASSAY_STAGE_ID,
    VITRO_REP.TREATMENT_DOSE(CSM_FLASKS.GROUP_ID)                                               AS TREATMENT_DOSE,
    MN_RI_REP.FLASK_BIN_VALUE_BY_INDEX(MN_ASSAYS_STAGES.ASSAY_STAGE_ID, CSM_FLASKS.FLASK_ID, 1) AS BIN1,
    MN_RI_REP.FLASK_BIN_VALUE_BY_INDEX(MN_ASSAYS_STAGES.ASSAY_STAGE_ID, CSM_FLASKS.FLASK_ID, 2) AS BIN2,
    MN_RI_REP.FLASK_BIN_VALUE_BY_INDEX(MN_ASSAYS_STAGES.ASSAY_STAGE_ID, CSM_FLASKS.FLASK_ID, 3) AS BIN3,
    MN_RI_REP.CBPI_FLASK(MN_ASSAYS_STAGES.ASSAY_STAGE_ID, CSM_FLASKS.FLASK_ID, 1, 2, 2)         AS CBPI,
    CSM_EXPERIMENTS.EXPT_CODE
  FROM CSM_TREATMENT_GROUPS_EXPTS
  INNER JOIN CSM_ASSAYS
  ON CSM_ASSAYS.EXPT_ID = CSM_TREATMENT_GROUPS_EXPTS.EXPERIMENT_ID
  INNER JOIN CSM_FLASKS
  ON CSM_TREATMENT_GROUPS_EXPTS.GROUP_ID = CSM_FLASKS.GROUP_ID
  INNER JOIN MN_ASSAYS
  ON CSM_ASSAYS.ASSAY_ID = MN_ASSAYS.ASSAY_ID
  INNER JOIN MN_ASSAYS_STAGES
  ON MN_ASSAYS.MN_ASSAY_ID = MN_ASSAYS_STAGES.MN_ASSAY_ID
  INNER JOIN CSM_EXPERIMENTS
  ON CSM_EXPERIMENTS.EXPT_ID    = CSM_TREATMENT_GROUPS_EXPTS.EXPERIMENT_ID
  AND CSM_EXPERIMENTS.EXPT_ID   = CSM_ASSAYS.EXPT_ID
  WHERE CSM_ASSAYS.ASSAY_ID     = 1000060
  AND MN_ASSAYS_STAGES.STAGE_ID = 2
  ORDER BY CSM_TREATMENT_GROUPS_EXPTS.ORDER_INDEX,
    CSM_FLASKS.FLASK_ID,
    CSM_FLASKS.IS_PLUS DESC
) T
```

Error:
ORA-00937: not a single-group group function
00937. 00000 -  "not a single-group group function"
*Cause:
*Action:
Error at Line: 1 Column: 9

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using any aggregate function, you will need to add the non aggregated fields into a `GROUP BY` clause. So in your  column you need to list those fields that are not listed in the aggregate function `SUM` in the `GROUP BY` clause. Therefore your query should be as following:

```
SELECT FLASK_CODE,
SUM(nvl(BIN1, 0)) + SUM(nvl(BIN2, 0)) + SUM(nvl((BIN3, 0)) AS TOTAL
FROM
(
  ...

) T
GROUP BY FLASK_CODE
```

This is just an example. But you have to determine what fields to select in the `SELECT` clause and needs to be listed too in `GROUP BY` clause.

Answer (score 1):

Try This:
If You add all Data in single column means:

```
select sum( column_name ) from table inner join .........;
```

Finally you find the total